POST request not being send even after adding the CORS origin in react app using express as backend hosted on cpanel
I wanted to host the react application on the cpanel .I created 2 different domains one for front end and the other one for the backend.
I have successfully created the backend and also added the cors origin of my frontend url. The GET request are successfully been send but when i try to send a post request it logs a message of file not found and in network it send a preflight request
I have stored all my routes in the routes folder of the backend and my starter file is index.js
It is giving me the error of header not sent. I have also added the helmet to the express for the necessary headers.
// Express server setup
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env' });

// Configure port
const port = process.env.PORT;
console.log(process.env.PORT);

// Import models and middleware
require('./models');
const helmet = require('helmet');

// Middleware setup
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://valpro.gnpomg.in' }));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Imp_Data',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 600000,
  }
}));

// Import and sync models
const app_mst_val_para = require('./models/app_mst_val_para');
const app_rechrg_trn_dtl = require('./models/app_rechrg_trn_dtl');
// Add imports for other models

app_mst_val_para.sync();
app_rechrg_trn_dtl.sync();
// Sync other models

// Import and setup routes
const app_mst_val_paraR = require('./routes/app_mst_val_para');
const login = require('./routes/login');
// Add imports for other routes

app.use('/amvp', app_mst_val_paraR);
app.use('/login', login);
// Add other route setups

// Default route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});

I tried adding the headers in the .htaccess file and also in the index.js file it stills shows me the same error`
